# Condition to distinguish frontend and back end

Tags: wordpress, function, conditional-statements

In my web site I am logged in as admin. I want to use a Condition to apply `add_filter` at front end. The same should not be applicable for back end.

Note: I am logged in both scenarios and also I tried using `!is_admin()` condition which also fails. Please suggest.

Comment: share your code

Answer (score -1):

For example: hook for non admin user is given below : hook can replace accordingly

```
if( !is_admin() ){
    add_filter('pre_get_posts','my_filter_the_search',10,1);
}
```

you can simply use

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','my_filter_the_search',10,1);
```